# Rails ajax render partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redmine

I want to implement simple feature.

When i click on checkbox

```
<%=check_box_tag :important_only,nil,false,id:'important-notes-only'%>
```

Data in view should be renewed

My controller action

```
  def important_notes
    deal =  Deal.find(params[:id])
    @notes = Note.where('is_important = ? and source_id = ?', true, deal.id)
    p @notes
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

route

```
      get 'important/:id' => 'notes#important_notes', :as => 'important'
```

and `important.js.erb`

```
should render my partial on view after click
```

How to do it?

my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#important-notes-only').click(function () {
    if ($('#important-notes-only').is(':checked')) {
        console.log('clicked')
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= important_notes_path(@deal.id) %>",

            success: render partial
            }
        })

    }
});
```

});
How to render partial on success

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
#app/views/notes/important_notes.js.erb
$(".element").html("<%=j render 'partial' %>");
```

This is assuming your other code is correct.

---

Looking at your updates, I would use the following:

```
#view
<%= check_box_tag :important_only, nil, false, id:'important-notes-only', data: { note: @deal.id } %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#important-notes-only", function(e){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $.get("important/" + $(this).attr("data-note"));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def important_notes
    deal =  Deal.find(params[:id])
    @notes = Note.where('is_important = ? and source_id = ?', true, deal.id)
    p @notes
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { }
      format.js{ render 'my_partial', :locals => { :if_any => @if_any } }
    end
end
```

on view

```
<%= check_box '/important/:id' , remote: true do %>
```

on my_partial.js

```
$('.element').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'my_partial', :locals => { :if_any => @if_any}) %>");
```